# forever doesn't play nice with cluster.js

Tags: node.js

Until recently I started my node server like such

```
node server/server.js
```

where server.js was a simple expresss server

```
var app = express();
app.listen(PORT...
```

Now I am using cluster.js to start my application

```
var cluster = require('cluster');

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  // Count the machine's CPUs
  var cpuCount = require('os').cpus().length;

  // Create a worker for each CPU
  for (var i = 0; i < cpuCount; i += 1) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  // Listen for dying workers
  cluster.on('exit', function () {
    cluster.fork();
  });
} else {
  require('./server');
}
```

When i start my server using

```
node server/cluster.js
```

It works fine. Cluster.js starts server.js which then starts my express server.. so far so good.

However when I attempt o use forever with cluster.js .. something goes amiss. it does start the cluster.js file..however the below command does not work

```
forever stop server/cluster.js
```

I do need the above command to work because I am using flightplan for deployment and it needs to stop and start forever before each deployment.

Any suggestions on how I can make this happen ?

Comment: any details about error? what's wrong? How it doesn't work? Error message?